# Path to archived iOS Framework

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone have a clue of where to find the archived iOS framework after successful archive in Xcode 8? I've been searching for hours.. The build is successful, but, the framework is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Xcode/DerivedData folder. Default path is `/Users/YourUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

Archived projects (Archives *.xcarchive) are under (default path) `/Users/YourUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` catalogued according to the creation date.

You can look up how those paths are set in your Xcode in the following menu: Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations (last tab). You can also change locations there.

I hope this will help you push your project further. Ania